# Modular Arithmetic in Haskell

Tags: haskell, math, modular

How would I go about making a function so that `x` has a range of values from `x=0` to `x=19` and if the `x` value exceeds 19 or is below zero how can I get it to wrap around

From:
`x=20, x=21, x=22` and `x=(-1), x=(-2), x=(-3)`

To:
`x=0, x=1, x=2` and `x=19, x=18, x=17` **respectively**?

I've heard of modular arithmetic which is apparently the way I should deal with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you would use the built-in functions `mod` and `rem`, but I assume they are off-limits for homework. So you can write your own function, e.g.

```
mod20 x | x < 0 = ...
        | x > 19 = ...
        | otherwise = x
```

There are different things you can try to fill in the `...`s. One of the easiest is repeated addition or subtraction, but I don't want to spoil all the fun.

Once you have this function, you can "rescale" the values after every "normal" arithmetic operation, e.g. `mod20 (12 + 17)`.

Comment: are `mod` and `rem` exactly the same things? They seem to be.

Comment: `mod` and `rem` behave differently when fed negative numbers; for positive numbers they're the same.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the mod function:

```
(-5) `mod` 20 ==> 15
5 `mod` 20 ==> 5
20 `mod` 20 ==> 0
25 `mod` 20 ==> 5
```

See also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) on the topic.

Comment: `mod (-5) 20 = 15`, `rem (-5) 20 = 5`

Comment: 25 `mod` 25 is not equal to 5

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
x `mod` 20
```

(This is a filler to make the answer 30 characters.)